# semistability of parabolic bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a rational curve and $E$ a stable parabolic vector bundle on $X$. Is the sheaf of parabolic endomorphisms (i.e the endomorphisms preserving the flag) of the sheaf $E$ also stable (or atleast semi-stable)?

Any suggestions or references will be helpful.

Comment: As your title indicates, you can only hope for semi-stability, since the endomorphisms sheaf has a trivial direct summand.

Comment: @abx but is it semi-stable atleast? Can you give a reference.